# How to print the value of variable in java

Tags: java

```
System.out.printf("The Sum is %d%n" , sum);
```

and the error is 
The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)

```
System.out.printf("The sum is " + sum);
```

Works but What if i need to print

> "The Sum of 5 and 6 is 11"

```
System.out.printf("The sum of %d and %d  is %d . " ,a,b,sum);
```

But got the above error on Eclipse Platform Version: 3.8.1 (Ubuntu)

Comment: The Error in  `System.out.printf("The Sum is %d%n" , sum);`  is the %n, You surely meant \n.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)

 at addition.main(addition.java:25) 

Is the error.

Comment: @Turo `%n` is valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `System.out.printf` is giving you this error:

```
 The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)
```

Then you must configure your project for the proper Java version.

Methods with variable arguments were introduced with Java 5.

Alternatively, you could do:

```
System.out.printf("The Sum of %d and %d is %d\n", new Object[] {a, b, sum});
```

Answer (score 4):

Have look at this question for your error: [Eclipse Java printf issue PrintStream is not applicable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218802/eclipse-java-printf-issue-printstream-is-not-applicable)

Alternatively you can use `.format`

```
System.out.format("The sum of %d and %d  is %d . " ,1, 2, 3);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

With proper Java version set `.printf` also works as expected

```
System.out.printf("The sum of %d and %d  is %d . " ,1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 int a = 2;
 int b = 4;
 int c = a + b;
 System.out.format("The sum of %d  and  %d is %d ", a, b, c);
```

This is simple way in the formatted output